# Retrieving the solar panel production hour by hour with Google Solar API

Tags: google-solar-api

The new Google Solar API allows you to get solar information for a building just by querying the API with a set of coordinates. For ex, that gives the number of solar panel you can put on a given roof, the total power they will generate during the year, a lot of financial information too, etc.

However, I've searched in the output format and I don't seem to find the estimated solar power interval data. I was expecting to be able to retrieve something like the solar panel power  production (in Watts) for each hour of a whole year but nothing along those lines.

Also, nothing mentions it in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/solar

I'm a bit surprised as this is to me one of the most valuable information you may need if you are using this API.

Am I missing something ? Or since the product is in beta, does anyone know if they plan to add that feature at some point ?

Thanks

Comment: Indeed you can't get that hourly information. If you want to see this feature I suggest you file a feature request to the public issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=1356349&template=1819865

Comment: Does it work now, did they implement it?